# Using the Tkinter radio-button widget for a GUI in my python application

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry, tkinter-scale

I'm developing a python application that models forex derivatives. The intent of the project is to create a GUI that can:

- create data models
- display visualizations of that data
- update the visuals while they're open
- quit all windows with one button

This all functions as intended.

Currently, the GUI uses 6 Tkinter 'entry' widgets and 5 Tkinter 'button' widgets.

[image: GUI example]

'Update' buttons use (their respective) entry fields to generate 'result-sets', which are then saved to .txt files.

'Display' buttons read data in the .txt files, and create visuals using Matplotlib's Animation function.

**What I want to do:** replace the 'size' entry field with: radio-button / checkbox / slider Tkinter widgets.

For example: Consider a user who wants to model the purchase of 10 forex contracts. Instead of typing 10 into the 'size' field (and clicking update), they mark the 10 radio-button and click 'update'.

**What I've attempted and failed to do:** I've read a number of Tkinter radio-button / checkbox widget tutorials which have been a waste of time. Honestly, I'm struggling to conceptualize how I can add this functionality.

If applicable, the GUI is formatted by a class.

Comment: You haven't really asked a question here.  You seem to have a good grasp of how to create and lay out Tkinter widgets, what goes wrong when you try to put a row of Radiobuttons where you currently have an Entry?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach imo would be a slider.

```
slider = tk.Scale(master, from_=0, to=10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
```

and then later make a function to get that chosen value from slider like:

`size = slider.get()`

Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me

Comment: I did not Sory. Tkinter really lacks tutorials and such. Everything I found also seemed to be copy and pasted from a single source.

Comment: I actually started some PyQt tutorials today. Tkinter is easy to learn, but it's extremely limited. PyQt has much broader applicability.

Comment: As you wish bro.